# How to calculate the effect of regression variables on the dependent variable in a neural network regression model?

Tags: regression, neural-networks

My Deep Neural Network regression model has three regression (input) variables: Age, Sex and Zip code. The dependent variable (output) is the NetWorth. I'd like to know how to calculate the influence of Age, Sex and Zip on NetWorth. In other kinds of models, I can get this information easily from the trained model by inspecting the trained model's coefficients or exp(coefficient) along with their standard errors.

For e.g. if a trained linear regression model produces coefficients 0.1, 0.3, 0.9 for Age, Sex and Zip with (for simplicity's sake) identical standard errors, it tells me that Zip is 3 times as influential as Age in predicting Net Worth.

Can such kinds of conclusions be drawn for a Deep Neural Network Regression model? Can someone point me to the relevant body of research?